# Disable live reload in Nest JS for certain directory

Tags: nestjs

In my code, I generate a 'downloads' folder in my project, and since I am using `nest start --watch` command I always get `"File change detected. Starting incremental compilation..."` How can I exclude the downloads folder from being checked by live reload?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution:

```
  "exclude": ["downloads"],
  "include": ["src"]
```